# How to update users that have 'old' banners?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In the past users have uploaded banners freely without validation. Just recently we rolled out validation with banners. How do we update user records that have OLD banners?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
  mount_uploader :banner, BannerUploader

  validate :banner_size_validation, :if => :banner?
  validate :check_banner_dimensions, :if => :banner?

  def banner_size_validation
    errors.add :banner, 'should be less than 1mb' if banner.size > 1.megabytes
  end

  def check_banner_dimensions
    tmp_banner = MiniMagick::Image.open(banner)
    errors.add :banner, 'height must be no more than 400px.' if tmp_banner[:height] > 400
  end
end
```

For example. User with ID 3 uploaded a banner at the time our validations were not enforced.

```
User.find(3).update_attributes!(:artist_name => 'vanilla')
# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Banner height must be no more than 400px.
```

Deleting banners might disappoint users. Resizing existing banners will make some banners look 'stretchy'. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can decide what to do depending on the count of users with old banners uploaded. Or you can add condition to your validation methods to check for banner creation date, so old banners wouldn`t be touched by these checks.

Comment: Actually I got it to work with a `Proc` and `banner_change?`